# advice on database index maintenance

Tags: sql-server-2005, maintenance

I have a fairly large table, which I have to keep up, with some very, very fragmented indices. This seems to be causing problems with performance. I would like to have neat fresh crisp indices on this table. I also have some rather annoying restrictions: 1. At no time can this table become unavailable. 2. I don't have Sql Server enterprise edition (i.e. no online rebuilding of indices)

What is my best course of action? Just try and reorganise them? How long would this roughly take on a table with about 600k rows, on moderate hardware? (answers within an order of magnitude are precise enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate index in off time OR do it without dropping it - SQL Server Enterprise edition ahs this feature, and a table which CAN NOT BECOME UNAVAILABLE needs enterprise edition. Sorry. Otherwise you are basically toast. I cant run a formula 1 race witha  street car. I cant fullfill enterprise high end requirements without the proper version.

> What is my best course of action? Just
>   try and reorganise them?

Yes. Choose your time wisely (i.e. off).

> How long would this roughly take on a
>   table with about 600k rows, on
>   moderate hardware?

Define moderate hardware? 4 cores, 16gb RAM, about 10 high end discs - possibly in the range of minutes (i was merging 650 million rows into a table on a mid range server in 10 minutes).

Note that your definition of "moderate" may vary - but anything that fits into one rack case is moderate for me.

Comment: 'I cant run a formula 1 race witha street car' It's daily practice for me. I just happen to end last on every race.

Comment: @Martijn - yup, sometimes we have to work under unrealistic constraints.